# Generating an audio track sound with given decibel

Tags: java, android, volume, audiotrack

I am using audio track to generate a beep sound with given frequency and decibels dB. In audio track there is a method called

```
setStereoVolume()
```

that gets left and right volume. However in this library the volume is set by amplitude which is in range of 0 -1 where 0 is min and 1 is max but my users give dB instead ,so I need to convert dB to amplitude . After searching I found the formula as `amp = 10^(dB/20)`. The problem is that for this formula only -ve dB works , for +ve dB the formula returns value above 1 which means max.

```
audioTrack.setStereoVolume((float) Math.pow(10,volumeL_val/20),(float) Math.pow(10,volumeR_val/20));
```

How can I convert +ve dB to amplitude in range 0-1 that is acceptable by Android?

Comment: You're going to need to scale the formula. In your case you're saying you don't want the standard (correct) dB to amplitude relationship. You could use `amp = 10^((dB-max_dB)/10)` where `max_dB` is the maximum dB you want to support.

Comment: i did that but i dont thnk so its giving the right ones..... eg: hearing of different frequency with dB between 0 - 20 where 0 is min ,means normal hearing level .... the formula you gave makes my dB works between 0 - 49 dB above that the amp value is more than 1 but still we have other level like eg:20 - 40 which is one level below the normal hearing